# JavaScript getElement for specific div

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm struggling to directly get an Element for NTP as the number of f-field tags varies. Here is an example with three f-field tags, for which this getElement call works:

```
document.getElementById("system-time-dlg").querySelector("section").getElementsByTagName('div')[4]
```

Because the number of f-field tags varies my getElement solution is not compatible for other numbers of. Those f-fields are also variable after the div NTP tag.

```html
    <div id="system-time-dlg" ng-if="!$ctrl.loading" class="ng-scope">
      <section>
        <f-field class="ng-isolate-scope">...</f-field>
        <f-field class="ng-isolate-scope">...</f-field>
        <f-field class="ng-isolate-scope">...</f-field>
        <div ng-if="$ctrl.timeMode === 'ntp'" class="ng-scope">
        <f-field class="ng-isolate-scope">...</f-field>
        ..
      </section>
```

Is there a way to precisely get the div element for NTP?

Comment: Give it a specific CSS class and then search by the class. Never search by tag name.

Comment: I also vote for using classes. It doesn't cost you anything (well hardly anything), and then you can have a lot more confidence that things will work (and keep working as your page structure evolves).

Comment: All the elements share the same ng-scope class. As this is not my website I can't give it any other classes by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom data attribute along with document.querySelector()

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the element is always the last then you can do this:

```
const elements = document.getElementById("system-time-dlg").querySelector("section").getElementsByTagName('div')
const element  = elements[elements.length - 1]
```

As others have suggested it's probably better to use a class name for this.

Comment: I wouldn't have asked here if it would be that simple. There is also a variable number of f-field tags after the NTP div. As they also share the same class that doesn't seem to be an option either.

Comment: @maria You can specify multiple class names for a single element.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
const fFields = document.querySelectorAll('#system-time-dlg section f-field');
const lastFFieldForNtp = fFields[fFields.length - 1];

if (lastFFieldForNtp.getAttribute('ng-if') === '$ctrl.timeMode === \'ntp\'') {
  // Do something with the last f-field element for NTP
}
```

Comment: The numbers of f-fields varies. There is also a variable number of f-field tags after the NTP div. That's why a I asked here because I don't find such a simple solution to count through by a number.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! here is an example, in html you want to add custom data attribute to the element you'd like to select. For example you want to select the div you can do this:

```
<section>
   <f-field class="ng-isolate-scope">...</f-field>
   <f-field class="ng-isolate-scope">...</f-field>
   <f-field class="ng-isolate-scope">...</f-field>
   // you want to select the following line
   <div ng-if="$ctrl.timeMode === 'ntp'" class="ng-scope" custom-attr="i-want-this">
   <f-field class="ng-isolate-scope">...</f-field>
        ..
</section>
```

to select the div, you can write
`document.querySelector('[custom-attr="i-want-this"]');`